# How to convert a Sitecore Item object into a strongly-typed Glass model?

Tags: glass-mapper

I have a Sitecore template `MyTemplate` and a corresponding Glass model `MySite.Model.MyTemplate`.

In my page code, I retrieve a raw `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item` object from a legacy data access class. This object represents an item of the template `MyTemplate`, but it is still a generic item object, so I have to access its fields like this: `item["FieldName"]`.

Is there a quick way to convert this `Item` object into a strongly-typed Glass model of the class `MySite.Model.MyTemplate`? I want to do this directly in my page code, without replacing the way in which I obtain the item object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instantiate a `SitecoreContext` and call the `Cast<T>()` method.

```cs
ISitecoreContext context = SitecoreContext.GetFromHttpContext();
var myTemplateObject = context.Cast<MySite.Model.MyTemplate>(item);
```

Comment: Thank you! And wouldn't it be even better to get the context like this instead? `var context = SitecoreContext.GetFromHttpContext();`

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko Yes probably, as it seems to cache stuff. :)

Answer (score 8):

Looks like `SitecoreContext.GetFromHttpContext()` is obsolete.

The recommend way  is `SitecoreContextFactory.Default.GetSitecoreContext()`

My preferred way is `new SitecoreContext()`

So casting can be done like:

```
var model = SitecoreContextFactory.Default.GetSitecoreContext().Cast<T>(item);
var model = new SitecoreContext().Cast<T>(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is GlassMapper specific but this works for me in my `9.1`

```
SitecoreService context = new SitecoreService(Sitecore.Context.Database);
MyModel rule = context.GetItem<MyModel>(item);
```